# Looking for datasets of complaints/requests filed at municipalities or cities

Tags: data-request, city, legal, text

I'm looking to do some text analysis on complaints or requests filed at cities or municipalities.

The data must have:

- type of complaint (e.g. "Noise complaint")
- complaint text (e.g.: "The people in the building across from me are having a party")

It would also be nice if there's more meta-data, such as:

- time of complaint
- location
- responsible department (e.g. "Police" or "Fire dept.")
- response (e.g. "warning issued")
- time of resolution

So far I've found various 311 datasets (such as the [New York](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/311-Service-Requests/fvrb-kbbt) one), but none of them contain the actual complaint text.

Preferably the data would be in English, Dutch or German, but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[US City Open Data Census results for Service Requests](http://us-city.census.okfn.org/dataset/service-requests) should have what you need. And there's always [Open 311](http://www.open311.org/), though I'm pretty sure its implementers will overlap with the census results.

There is also [Open Referrals](https://openreferral.org/), an initiative developing common standards and open platforms for the sharing of community resource directory data — i.e., information about the health, human and social services that are available to people in need. More background information:
 [Introducing Open Referral: Open211+Open311 protocols for health/human/social services](http://lists.open311.org/groups/discuss/messages/topic/ZiuhI9VPfx445gmjspovI) and [Open Referral Initiative: A Standard for the Safety Net](https://www.codeforamerica.org/blog/2014/08/05/open-referral-initiative-a-standard-for-the-safety-net/).

Comment: Open 311 looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for. The census data points towards the 311 datasets I'd found before that doesn't contain the raw complaint text.

Comment: sweet! check out open referrals too! my bad for leaving them out.

Comment: Open Referral also looks very interesting, definitely something I will dive into.   As for the Open 311 dataset, without diving into the API I've only been able to get the last 48 hours worth of data. Am I correct in assuming that I can get more and older data through the API?

Comment: i couldn't say...join their slack or google group if you can't find it in the documentation